# Sql Query in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i have two tables, products table and its photos table. I want to query products with one of their photo. my below sql query give me the result but in laravel i don't know how to use functions to take same result.

```
  select products.*, pphotos.name as pname from products 
         INNER JOIN pphotos on products.id = pphotos.product_id
         GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: This query is unpredictable in which photo it is going to pick for each product. It will be one of the products' photos, but you cant tell which.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the query builder https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->select('products.*', 'pphotos.name as pname')
    ->join('pphotos', 'products.id', '=', 'pphotos.product_id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

#### Edit

To work around the issue where an item in your select list is not functionally dependent, you can modify the query like so:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
    ->selectRaw('products.*, ANY_VALUE(pphotos.name) as pname')
    ->join('pphotos', 'products.id', '=', 'pphotos.product_id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->get();
```

or you can simply disable strict mode in your config/db.php

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'strict' => false,
]
```

**Disclaimer**

However, note that if the pphotos.name within the same group differ in value, it will be unpredictable which pphotos.name mysql will return as a result.

Comment: this query you wrote i know about this but i couldn't do with it Group By.

Comment: oh, in that case, you simply need to add `->groupBy('products.id')` before the `->get()` method. Let me edit it for you.

Comment: ERROR. Select list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'photos.name is not functionally dependent on columns in Group By clause.

Comment: Then you must have strict mode set to on. You can either modify the query so that you can work around the "non-functionally dependent" issue or set your strict mode to false in your config/db.php. I'll edit my answer again to show you what I exactly mean.

Comment: But I don't understand why it is like this.

Comment: It’s because your pphotos.name is a non-aggregated column while not included in the groupBy clause. Imagine if you had to group this query manually yourself, and for products.id = 1 you have 5 pphotos that match, each of the pphoto have a different name. You won’t know which pphoto.name to choose for the result. So the ANY_VALUE tells mysql to choose any value from the result. This is useful if you expect the values of pphotos.name to be the same within the group.